# How to fix ! Package ifluatex Error: Name clash, \ifluatex is already defined

Tags: texlive, mactex

I'm using a 2017 MacBook Pro, running Big Sur 11.4. About a month ago I upgraded to the latest version of mactex. Just now I tried to run the pandoc command below and got the following error:

```
pandoc README.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o test.pdf
Error producing PDF.
! Package ifluatex Error: Name clash, \ifluatex is already defined.

See the ifluatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.174     }
```

I tried to find a solution to this problem here and in other places, and none of them solved my problem. The closest I found was to update texlive, so I did that, even though it was current as of my latest mactex install about a month ago. Below is a partial result of the complete update that I just ran:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty

! Package ifluatex Error: Name clash, \ifluatex is already defined.

See the ifluatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.174     }
           %
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.174     }
           %
No pages of output.
Transcript written on jadetex.log.
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=jadetex -progname=jadetex *jadetex.ini </dev/null' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/jadetex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: disabled formats: 5
fmtutil [INFO]: not selected formats: 53
fmtutil [INFO]: failed to build: 1 (pdftex/jadetex)
fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 59
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 1
  ERROR: jadetex.fmt/pdftex
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt xelatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/c9Wido6ce_/I3ei347pOz ...
done running fmtutil-sys --byfmt xelatex --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/c9Wido6ce_/I3ei347pOz.
```

This output shows that I'm getting the same error while trying to update the ifluatex package as I was while trying to use it before updating. And I still get the same error when trying to again run the pandoc command. Any suggestions on how to remedy this situation?

Do I have to remove the entire mactex installation and reinstall it again? I checked in /usr/local/texlive and verified that only the 2021 version is there, so there should be no conflicts with older versions.

Comment: you seem to have local (and probably old) files in texmf-local.

Comment: ifluatex.sty is a legacy package that just onputs iftex so you could fix it by using iftex package instead, but you should also delete the old copies you have in texmf-local

Comment: I don't want to start deleting stuff unless I know what I'm doing. In /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex there is a directory called oberdiek. All the files in the oberdiek folder are dated 2016 and 2017, back to the time I purchased this computer and first installed mactex. What is safe to delete and what needs replacing and/or updating? This problem is associated with a pandoc script, so I can't mess with that.

Comment: The problem is definitely related to something old in texmf-local. I renamed texmf-local and replaced it with an empty texmf-local. The problem went away. Now to determine which old files to remove from the old texmf-local.